# Codeigniter multi image upload error message

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

I have a problem with my multi image upload.

The code

```
function tester($yourUniqueId){

             $this->load->library('upload'); 

             for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES); $i++)
             {

               $_FILES['userfile']['name']    = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$i];
               $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $_FILES['filename']['type'][$i];
               $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
               $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $_FILES['filename']['error'][$i];
               $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $_FILES['filename']['size'][$i];

                $path = './uploads/' . $yourUniqueId;
                mkdir($path);

               $config['file_name']     = "kep_" . $i;
               $config['upload_path']   =  $path;
               $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
               $config['max_size']      = '0';
               $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

              $this->upload->initialize($config);

              if($this->upload->do_upload())
              {
                $error += 0;

              }else{
                $error += 1;
                }
             }

                 if($error > 0){ 

                    return FALSE; 
                    }else{
                         return TRUE; 

                     }



}
```

Its a bit strange, because, it it returns false, and i give it an echo

```
if($error > 0){ 
echo 'Something went wrong'; //just for a test                   
return FALSE;
```

Doesnt it sopose to show the echo?

I cant make it work.

Is there something worng with the code?

Could please someone give me a hint?
I cant see it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error += 0;
}else{
    $error += 1;
}
```

With this:

```
if ( !$this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error++;
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
```

That should tell you what went wrong.  You also might want to wrap the mkdir() function just in case the directory does exist (I don't know how PHP handles it otherwise--might be returning early):

```
if ( !is_dir($path))
{
    mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE); // make it writable!
}
```